# How can I get the total number of documents found using the Nest?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I do the same request using the nest, and directly in ElastichSearch. 
When I see direct request, how many documents match request.

```
  "hits": 
  {
    "total": 1640,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [...]
   }
```

My query:

```
 var search = client.Search<RCompany>(s => s.Index("MyIndex")
 .Query(qq => qq
 .Filtered(m => m.Filter(f => f.Bool(b => b
 .Must(
 a => a.Term(z => z.Company.Code, param1),
 a => a.Terms(z => z.Company.Id, param2),
 a => a.Terms(z => z.Company.Field1.Id, param3)
  )))
 .Query(b => b.Bool(q => q.Should
  (n => n.Match(a => a.OnField(d => d.Company.Field2).Query(param5).Operator(Operator.And)),
   n => n.Match(a => a.OnField(d => d.Company.Field3).Query(param5).Operator(Operator.And)),
   n => n.Match(a => a.OnField(d => d.Company.Field4).Query(param5).Operator(Operator.And)),
   n => n.Match(a => a.OnField(d => d.Company.Field5).Query(param5).Operator(Operator.And))
  )))))
  .Size(10)
  .SortDescending(n => n.DtCreate));
```

How can I find out how many documents suitable request using Nest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a `Total` property on `ISearchResponse` which holds the total number of documents that matched the query.  In your example, that would be `search.Total`.

Comment: Thank you, Greg! Made several requests, but in total has always been the number 10, which coincides with my Size. This is misleading.

Comment: `Size` and `Total` are two different things.  `Size` indicates the number of results to return with the request (the default is 10) and is used in conjunction with `From` (the offset to start from in the index).  These are useful for pagination.  `Total` on the other hand is the actual number of documents that matched the query.

Comment: is there a way to get the total if the result size is > 10000?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use the method **Count** as proposed by the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/count.html)

here the code

```
var result = client.Count<ElasticsearchProject>();
```